# Probability Modem is Defective

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> A store has 80 modems in its inventory, 30 coming from Source A and
>   the remainder from Source B. Of the modems from Source A, 20% are
>   defective. Of the modems from Source B, 8% are defective. Calculate
>   the probability that exactly two out of a random sample of five modems
>   from the store’s inventory are defective.
>
> (A) 0.010 (B) 0.078 (C) 0.102 (D) 0.105 (E) 0.125

---

A: Modem is from source A, P(A) = 30/80

B: Modem is from source B, P(B) = 50/80

To have 2 defective modems we could have AA (1st and 2nd defective modem from A), AB (1st defective modem from A, 2nd from B), BA, BB.

The probability of choosing each modem and each being defective is thus:

P(exactly 2 defective) = $\frac{30}{80}\frac{29}{79}(0.2^2)+\frac{30}{80}\frac{50}{79}(0.2*.08)*2+\frac{50}{80}\frac{49}{79}(0.08^2) = 0.016$

**My answer didn't match any of the choices, what flaw am I making in my thinking?**

---

**Edit:** I know the correct answer, and saw a solution using combinations, but I want to know if there is another way to solve the problem taking an approach similar to mine.

The binomial approach the other posters used led to the wrong result as well. What mistake is being made?

Comment: What about the "random sample of five" ?

Comment: Your answer seems to combine sampling without replacement (denom 79) and with replacement (squares), also it does not specifically require three good modems out of 5 along with the two bad ones, creating a possibility of overlap in events you intended to be mutually exclusive. See hypergeometric approach in my (new) Answer.

Comment: On second thoughts, I suggest you ask your teacher what is wrong with using the binomial distribution, as I  originally did. Normally, for a hypergeometric  distribution, we are **told** how many defectives there are  in the lot. Here, why should we use it just because the **expected** value of # of defectives **happens** to be an integer. How does this become a **general** way of solving problems framed in this way ?

Comment: @true blue anil. This illustrates one of many reasons don't like multiple choice tests. let me list some faults with this question: Two answers are very close, many texts would consider either of them correct. A student who picks either of them clearly knows some basic probability theory and how to apply it. A student who picks .105 is graded the same as one who picks ,010. In practice it would take several thousand performances of this 'experiment' to distinguish between .102 and .105. There are many better ways to see if a student knows the difference between binomial and hypergeometric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good grief!  Sorry, misread the problem. With your prompting (and some coffee with lunch), I think I have it right now.

Altogether, there are 10 defectives among 80. You are selecting
five *out of those 80,* and you want the probability of getting exactly two defectives. This is hypergeometric.

$$P(X = 2) = \frac{{10 \choose 2}{70 \choose 3}}{{80 \choose 5}}
= 0.1024667.$$

In R statistical software:

```
 dhyper(2, 10, 70, 5)
 ## 0.1024667
 choose(10,2)*choose(70,3)/choose(80,5)
 ## 0.1024667
```

Comment: I got $p(D) = 0.125$ and $n = 5$ trials, and the number of successes $= 2$,using those values in this calculator: http://stattrek.com/online-calculator/binomial.aspx I got 0.105, which is incorrect. The answer should be (C)

Comment: That is correct, and the same solution as the book. So how can we rule out binomial? Also, where am I going wrong with my approach?

Comment: The binomial would be OK as an approximation if you were sampling from a larger population. (Also, if you were sampling with replacement from among the 80, but that makes no practical sense in this problem.) For example, in R, `dhyper(2, 1000, 7000, 5)` returns approx  0.105, same as binomial answer. Enough clarification?

Comment: I appreciate the clarification! I assume the test makers included the 0.105 because they expected that many people would fall for it. So when dealing with small populations opt for hypergeometric? What would be considered small? What I really want to know is, how do you know when you should used hypergeometric instead of binomial, and vice versa to avoid falling for the test makers trap?

Comment: With only hand calculators, I consider such close answers to be a poor choice for a multiple choice exam. Hypergeometric (sampling without replacement), Binomial (independent draws, sampling with replacement). Texts vary as to advice about when binomial is an acceptable approximation to hypergeometric: One common rule is that approx is OK if sample size is less than 10% (or 5%, being more fussy) of population size. This case exceeds 5%, not 10%.

Answer (score 0):

I believe an approximation is involved.

The weighted average % defective = $\frac{30}{80}\cdot{20} + \frac{50}{80}\cdot{8} = 12.5$

Now apply binomial(5,0.125) which yields P(2 defective) = $\frac{1715}{16384} \approx 0.105$,

*Edit*

There are differing thumb rules as to when the binomial approximation to the hypergeometric can be used. Here, it appears, we have to go by the *expected* number of defectives of 10, and apply the hypergeometric formula to get an answer of 0.102, as Bruce Trumbo has done.

Comment: The correct answer is (C) if that helps

Comment: This amounts to binomial approx. to hypergeometric. But note answers .102 and .105 are _very_ close together, so an approximation is not good enough. (Essentially the same mistake I made on my first try.)